# AffableBean throwing SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value Error Code: 1364

Tags: java, ejb, netbeans-8

I am trying to learn netbeans as my new IDE and also learning about EJB 3. I am doing the affableBean tutorial(https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/transaction.html) great tutorial by the way,I got to the point where I am learning about the transaction, so i follow along and get the null ID(in order.getId) error the tutorial says I'll get, to fix this it says to add 'em.flush();', but adding this gets me another error 'java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value Error Code: 1364', so now I am stuck.

the code I have is:

```
@Stateless
public class OrderManager {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AffableBeanPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public int placeOrder(String name, String email, String phone, String address, String cityRegion, String ccNumber, ShoppingCart cart) {
        Customer customer = addCustomer(name, email, phone, address, cityRegion, ccNumber);
        CustomerOrder order = addOrder(customer, cart);
        addOrderedItems(order, cart); 
        return order.getId();

    }

    private Customer addCustomer(String name, String email, String phone, String address, String cityRegion, String ccNumber) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName(name);
        customer.setEmail(email);
        customer.setPhone(phone);
        customer.setAddress(address);
        customer.setCityRegion(cityRegion);
        customer.setCcNumber(ccNumber);

        em.persist(customer);


        return customer;
    }

    private CustomerOrder addOrder(Customer customer, ShoppingCart cart) {
        // set up customer order
        CustomerOrder order = new CustomerOrder();
        order.setCustomer(customer);
        order.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(cart.getTotal()));

        // create confirmation number
        Random random = new Random();
        int i = random.nextInt(999999999);
        order.setConfirmationNumber(i);

        em.persist(order);

        return order;    
    }

    private void addOrderedItems(CustomerOrder order, ShoppingCart cart) {

        em.flush();

        List<ShoppingCartItem> items = cart.getItems();

        // iterate through shopping cart and create OrderedProducts
        for (ShoppingCartItem scItem : items) {

            int productId = scItem.getProduct().getId();

            // set up primary key object
            OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK = new OrderedProductPK();
            orderedProductPK.setCustomerOrderId(order.getId());
            orderedProductPK.setProductId(productId);

            // create ordered item using PK object
            OrderedProduct orderedItem = new OrderedProduct(orderedProductPK);

            // set quantity 
            orderedItem.setQuantity(scItem.getQuantity());

            em.persist(orderedItem);

        }
    }


}
```

my checkout.jsp:

```
<div id="singleColumn">

    <h2>checkout</h2>

    <p>In order to purchase the items in your shopping cart, please provide us with the following information:</p>

    <form action="<c:url value='purchase'/>" method="post">
        <table id="checkoutTable">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="name">name:</label></td>
                <td class="inputField">
                    <input type="text"
                           size="31"
                           maxlength="45"
                           id="name"
                           name="name"
                           value="${param.name}">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="email">email:</label></td>
                <td class="inputField">
                    <input type="text"
                           size="31"
                           maxlength="45"
                           id="email"
                           name="email"
                           value="${param.email}">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="phone">phone:</label></td>
                <td class="inputField">
                    <input type="text"
                           size="31"
                           maxlength="16"
                           id="phone"
                           name="phone"
                           value="${param.phone}">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="address">address:</label></td>
                <td class="inputField">
                    <input type="text"
                           size="31"
                           maxlength="45"
                           id="address"
                           name="address"
                           value="${param.address}">

                    <br>
                    prague
                    <select name="cityRegion">
                      <c:forEach begin="1" end="10" var="regionNumber">
                        <option value="${regionNumber}"
                                <c:if test="${param.cityRegion eq regionNumber}">selected</c:if>>${regionNumber}</option>
                      </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="creditcard">credit card number:</label></td>
                <td class="inputField">
                    <input type="text"
                           size="31"
                           maxlength="19"
                           id="creditcard"
                           name="creditcard"
                           value="${param.creditcard}">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit purchase">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <div id="infoBox">

        <ul>
            <li>Next-day delivery is guaranteed</li>
            <li>A &euro; ${initParam.deliverySurcharge}
                delivery surcharge is applied to all purchase orders</li>
        </ul>

        <table id="priceBox">
            <tr>
                <td>subtotal:</td>
                <td class="checkoutPriceColumn">
                    &euro; ${cart.subtotal}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>delivery surcharge:</td>
                <td class="checkoutPriceColumn">
                    &euro; ${initParam.deliverySurcharge}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="total">total:</td>
                <td class="total checkoutPriceColumn">
                    &euro; ${cart.total}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

my entities:

customer

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByEmail", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByPhone", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.phone = :phone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByAddress", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.address = :address"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByCityRegion", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.cityRegion = :cityRegion"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByCcNumber", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.ccNumber = :ccNumber")})
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "city_region")
    private String cityRegion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cc_number")
    private String ccNumber;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customer")
    private Collection<CustomerOrder> customerOrderCollection;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Customer(Integer id, String name, String email, String phone, String address, String cityRegion, String ccNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.cityRegion = cityRegion;
        this.ccNumber = ccNumber;
    }
//getters and setters
```

ordered_product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordered_product")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrderedProduct.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderedProduct o"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrderedProduct.findByCustomerOrderId", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderedProduct o WHERE o.orderedProductPK.customerOrderId = :customerOrderId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrderedProduct.findByProductId", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderedProduct o WHERE o.orderedProductPK.productId = :productId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrderedProduct.findByQuantity", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderedProduct o WHERE o.quantity = :quantity")})
public class OrderedProduct implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private short quantity;
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product product;
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_order_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private CustomerOrder customerOrder;

    public OrderedProduct() {
    }

    public OrderedProduct(OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK) {
        this.orderedProductPK = orderedProductPK;
    }

    public OrderedProduct(OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK, short quantity) {
        this.orderedProductPK = orderedProductPK;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public OrderedProduct(int customerOrderId, int productId) {
        this.orderedProductPK = new OrderedProductPK(customerOrderId, productId);
    }

//getters and setters
```

product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.price = :price"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByDescription", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.description = :description"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByLastUpdate", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.lastUpdate = :lastUpdate")})
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Category category;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Product(Integer id, String name, BigDecimal price, Date lastUpdate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }
//getters and setters
```

the error I get:

```
Muy Detallado:   TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Muy Detallado:   acquire unit of work: 1198625064
Más Detallado:   persist() operation called on: entity.Customer[id=null].
Más Detallado:   persist() operation called on: entity.CustomerOrder[id=null].
Muy Detallado:   begin unit of work flush
Muy Detallado:   TX beginTransaction, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Más Detallado:   Execute query InsertObjectQuery(entity.Customer[id=null])
Más Detallado:   Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
Más Detallado:   reconnecting to external connection pool
Detallado:   INSERT INTO customer (address, cc_number, city_region, email, name, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [6 parameters bound]
Más Detallado:   Execute query ValueReadQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY" sql="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
Detallado:   SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
Más Detallado:   assign sequence to the object (4 -> entity.Customer[id=null])
Más Detallado:   Execute query InsertObjectQuery(entity.CustomerOrder[id=null])
Detallado:   INSERT INTO customer_order (amount, confirmation_number, date_created, customer_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
Detallado:   SELECT 1
Advertencia:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
Error Code: 1364
Call: INSERT INTO customer_order (amount, confirmation_number, date_created, customer_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(entity.CustomerOrder[id=null])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.flush(EntityManagerWrapper.java:437)
    at session.OrderManager.addOrderedItems(OrderManager.java:72)
    at session.OrderManager.placeOrder(OrderManager.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy263.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
    at session.__EJB31_Generated__OrderManager__Intf____Bean__.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
    at controller.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:204)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at filter.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:892)
    ... 107 more
```

Comment: Your not passing a value for the id, and presumably the column isn't set up to have a default?

Comment: @SteveSmith the tutprial says "The getId method attempts to get the ID of an order which is currently in the process of being created. Since the ID is an auto-incrementing primary key, the database automatically generates the value only when the record is added. One way to overcome this is to manually synchronize the persistence context with the database. This can be accomplished using the EntityManager's flush method." so i assume that the "em.flush();" at the beggining of the addOrderedItems would fix this, or am i missing something?

Comment: I found the answer, took me a while, but the problem was in the DB, where the column customer_order.id wasn't set to AI.